# I cannot see the new row that I inserted from another schema - Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, schema, database-administration

I have permissions for select, insert, update, and delete rows from one schema to another, but when I insert a new row from schema A in a table of schema B, then I make select * from table in schema B I cannot see the new row, but when I make select * from table in schema A I can see the inserted row. I only can see the new row from the schema where did it the insertion.

I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you commit? Maybe you have a table with the same name in both schemas?

Comment: Thank you, my friend. I didn't make 'commit'. That was the solution. :)